# ayuda consulta mysql no regresa nada

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tengo esta consulta pero no me regresa nada, solo me regresa cuando todos los datos estan completos, si solo pongo una ciudad no regresa nada intente tronar la consulta pero aun asi no regresa nada, como q no entra algun consejo?

Modelo

```
$and1 = '';
        $and2 = '';
        $and3 = '';
        $and4 = '';
        $and5 = '';

        $month1 = date('m');
        $year1 = date('Y');
        $fecha3 = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0, $month1, 1, $year1));

      $month2 = date('m');
      $year2 = date('Y');
      $day2 = date("d", mktime(0,0,0, $month2+1, 0, $year2)); 
      $fecha4 = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0, $month2, $day2, $year2));


if($fecha == '' and $fecha2 == ''){$and3 = 'AND val.val_id_asessor = '.$asesor.'';}

elseif ($fecha2 == '' && $asesor == '') {$and1 = 'AND val.val_fecha_registro >= "'.$fecha.'"';}

elseif ($asesor == '') {$and2 = 'AND val.val_fecha_registro between "'.$fecha.'" and "'.$fecha2.'"';}

elseif ($asesor == '' && $fecha == '') {$and4 = 'AND val.val_fecha_registro >= "'.$fecha2.'"';}

elseif($fecha2 == ''){$and5 = 'AND val.val_fecha_registro >= "'.$fecha.'" AND val.val_id_asessor = "'.$asesor.'"';}

elseif($ciudad == 'Todos' && $asessor == '' && $fecha == '' && $fecha2 == ''){

                    $qry = 'SELECT val.idval_valuaciones AS id,
                   val.val_fecha_registro AS fecha_registro,
                   val.val_nom_contacto AS contacto_nombre,
                   val.val_modelo AS modelo,
                   val.val_aps AS aps,
                   val.val_id_asessor AS ase,
                   val.val_ciudad AS ciudad,
                   CONCAT( u.hus_nombre, " ", u.hus_apellido ) AS asessor
                   FROM valuaciones_seminuevos AS val
                   LEFT JOIN huser u ON u.hus_IDhuser = val.val_id_asessor
                   WHERE val.val_fecha_registro between "'.$fecha3.'" and "'.$fecha4.'"';

                return $this->db->query($qry)->result();

}elseif ($ciudad == 'Ti' || $ciudad == 'Me' || $ciudad == 'Af' && $asesor == '' && $fecha == '' && $fecha2 == '') {

                $qry = 'SELECT val.idval_valuaciones AS id,
                   val.val_fecha_registro AS fecha_registro,
                   val.val_nom_contacto AS contacto_nombre,
                   val.val_modelo AS modelo,
                   val.val_aps AS aps,
                   val.val_id_asessor AS ase,
                   val.val_ciudad AS ciudad,
                   CONCAT( u.hus_nombre,"", u.hus_apellido ) AS asessor
                   FROM valuaciones_seminuevos AS val
                   LEFT JOIN huser u ON u.hus_IDhuser = val.val_id_asessor
                   WHERE val.val_fecha_registro between "'.$fecha3.'" and "'.$fecha4.'"
                   AND val.val_ciudad = "'.$ciudad.'"';

                return $this->db->query($qry)->result();

}elseif($asesor == '' && $fecha == '' && $fecha2 == ''){

                    $qry = 'SELECT val.idval_valuaciones AS id,
                   val.val_fecha_registro AS fecha_registro,
                   val.val_nom_contacto AS contacto_nombre,
                   val.val_modelo AS modelo,
                   val.val_aps AS aps,
                   val.val_id_asessor AS ase,
                   val.val_ciudad AS ciudad,
                   CONCAT( u.hus_nombre," ", u.hus_apellido ) AS asessor
                   FROM valuaciones_seminuevos AS val
                   LEFT JOIN huser u ON u.hus_IDhuser = val.val_id_asessor
                WHERE val.val_ciudad = "'.$ciudad.'"
                AND val.val_id_asessor = "'.$asesor.'"
                AND val.val_fecha_registro between "'.$fecha.'"and "'.$fecha2.'"';

                return $this->db->query($qry)->result();
}else{

        $qry = 'SELECT val.idval_valuaciones AS id,
                   val.val_fecha_registro AS fecha_registro,
                   val.val_nom_contacto AS contacto_nombre,
                   val.val_modelo AS modelo,
                   val.val_aps AS aps,
                   val.val_id_asessor AS ase,
                   val.val_ciudad AS ciudad,
                   CONCAT( u.hus_nombre,"", u.hus_apellido ) AS asessor
                   FROM valuaciones_seminuevos AS val
                   LEFT JOIN huser u ON u.hus_IDhuser = val.val_id_asessor
                WHERE val.val_ciudad = "'.$ciudad.'"
                '.$and1.'
                '.$and2.'
                '.$and3.'
                '.$and4.'
                '.$and5.'';

        return $this->db->query($qry)->result();}
```

Controlador, loq solo marca es

```
"Status" => false,
                                "Message" => "GET"

$ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
        $asesor = $_POST['asesor'];
        $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
        $fecha2 = $_POST['fecha2'];


        $data = $this->valuaciones->busqueda_valuaciones($ciudad,$fecha,$fecha2,$asesor);
        if ($data) {

                        $this->output
                        ->set_content_type('application/json')
                        ->set_status_header(200)
                        ->set_output(json_encode(array(
                            "Status" => true,
                            "Message" => "GET",
                            "Data" =>  $data
                        )));
                    }else
                    { 
                         $this->output
                        ->set_content_type('application/json')
                        ->set_status_header(500)
                        ->set_output(json_encode(array(
                            "Status" => false,
                            "Message" => "GET"

                        )));
                    }
```

Comment: Ha que te refieres al decir: "solo me regresa cuando todos los datos están completos"?, en el WHERE si un dato esta vació, por obvias razones no te va a traer nada.

Comment: si pongo la pura ciudad me manda nada, intente tronar la consulta por si algo esta mal pero no solo me marca indefinidas  todas las variables, estoy usando , API testing y ahi le estoy mandando la ciudad, en el controlador imprimi la ciudad y si la imprime

Comment: Si le tiras un echo a tus variables que cachas en el post, te traen datos?

Comment: si me trae lo que tienen las variables, mis variables (ciudad, asesor,fecha,fecha2), tienen algo si se ejecuta bien, pero si solo ciudad tiene algo no imprime nada, igual si ciudad y asesor tienen algo tampoco manda nada

Comment: Creo que tu error esta en el acomodo de los operadores logicos (&& ||) de tus condiciones if, necesitas separarlos entre parentesis para que PHP los interprete correctamente, prueba separandolos y me cuentas.

Comment: no creo que sea eso, estoy comentando todo y estoy llendome uno por uno en las consultas para ver si entran pero si estan entrando bien, lo que estoy notando en el API test es que como q no hagarra campos null entonces asesor y fechas los estoy poniendo con espacios y e tenido resultados

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85253/discussion-between-ricardo-and-juan-jose).

Comment: no fue eso sigo igual

Comment: @JuanJose lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código tiene algunos errores, en cuestión de los `if`, necesitas separarlos por segmentos, ya que estas juntando todos en uno solo, y por esa razón nunca entraran a tus consultas:

```
$and1 = ''; 
$and2 = ''; 
$and3 = ''; 
$and4 = ''; 
$and5 = ''; 

$month1 = date('m'); 
$year1 = date('Y'); 
$fecha3 = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0, $month1, 1, $year1)); 

$month2 = date('m'); 
$year2 = date('Y'); 
$day2 = date("d", mktime(0,0,0, $month2+1, 0, $year2)); 
$fecha4 = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0, $month2, $day2, $year2)); 


if ($asesor == null) { 
$asesor = ''; 
} 
if ($ciudad == null) { 
$ciudad = ''; 
} 
if ($fecha == null) { 
$fecha = ''; 
} 
if ($fecha2 == null) { 
$fecha2 = ''; 
} 

if($fecha == '' && $fecha2 == ''){$and3 = 'AND val.val_id_asessor = '.$asesor.'';} 

elseif ($fecha2 == '' && $asesor == '') {$and1 = 'AND val.val_fecha_registro >= "'.$fecha.'"';} 

elseif ($asesor == '' && $fecha != '') {$and2 = 'AND val.val_fecha_registro between "'.$fecha.'" and "'.$fecha2.'"';} 

elseif ($asesor == '' && $fecha == '') {$and4 = 'AND val.val_fecha_registro >= "'.$fecha2.'"';} 

elseif($fecha2 == ''){$and5 = 'AND val.val_fecha_registro >= "'.$fecha.'" AND val.val_id_asessor = "'.$asesor.'"';} 


if($ciudad == 'Todos' && $asesor == '' && $fecha == '' && $fecha2 == ''){ 

$qry = 'SELECT val.idval_valuaciones AS id, 
val.val_fecha_registro AS fecha_registro, 
val.val_nom_contacto AS contacto_nombre, 
val.val_modelo AS modelo, 
val.val_aps AS aps, 
val.val_id_asessor AS ase, 
val.val_ciudad AS ciudad, 
val.val_servicio AS servicio, 
val.val_seminuevos AS seminuevo, 
val.val_ventas AS ventas, 
val.val_gte_ven AS gerente, 
val.val_contabilidad as conta, 
CONCAT( u.hus_nombre, " ", u.hus_apellido ) AS asessor 
FROM valuaciones_seminuevos AS val 
LEFT JOIN huser u ON u.hus_IDhuser = val.val_id_asessor 
WHERE val.val_fecha_registro between "'.$fecha3.'" and "'.$fecha4.'"'; 

return $this->db->query($qry)->result(); 

}elseif (($ciudad == 'Tijuana' || $ciudad == 'Mexicali' || $ciudad == 'Ensenada') && $asesor == '' && $fecha == '' && $fecha2 == '') { 

$qry = 'SELECT val.idval_valuaciones AS id, 
val.val_fecha_registro AS fecha_registro, 
val.val_nom_contacto AS contacto_nombre, 
val.val_modelo AS modelo, 
val.val_aps AS aps, 
val.val_id_asessor AS ase, 
val.val_ciudad AS ciudad, 
val.val_servicio AS servicio, 
val.val_seminuevos AS seminuevo, 
val.val_ventas AS ventas, 
val.val_gte_ven AS gerente, 
val.val_contabilidad as conta, 
CONCAT( u.hus_nombre,"", u.hus_apellido ) AS asessor 
FROM valuaciones_seminuevos AS val 
LEFT JOIN huser u ON u.hus_IDhuser = val.val_id_asessor 
WHERE val.val_fecha_registro between "'.$fecha3.'" and "'.$fecha4.'" 
AND val.val_ciudad = "'.$ciudad.'"'; 

return $this->db->query($qry)->result(); 

}elseif($ciudad == 'Todos' && $fecha == '' && $fecha2 == '') 
{ 
$qry = 'SELECT val.idval_valuaciones AS id, 
val.val_fecha_registro AS fecha_registro, 
val.val_nom_contacto AS contacto_nombre, 
val.val_modelo AS modelo, 
val.val_aps AS aps, 
val.val_id_asessor AS ase, 
val.val_ciudad AS ciudad, 
val.val_servicio AS servicio, 
val.val_seminuevos AS seminuevo, 
val.val_ventas AS ventas, 
val.val_gte_ven AS gerente, 
val.val_contabilidad as conta, 
CONCAT( u.hus_nombre,"", u.hus_apellido ) AS asessor 
FROM valuaciones_seminuevos AS val 
LEFT JOIN huser u ON u.hus_IDhuser = val.val_id_asessor 
WHERE val.val_id_asessor = "'.$asesor.'"'; 


return $this->db->query($qry)->result(); 

} else { 
$qry = 'SELECT val.idval_valuaciones AS id, 
val.val_fecha_registro AS fecha_registro, 
val.val_nom_contacto AS contacto_nombre, 
val.val_modelo AS modelo, 
val.val_aps AS aps, 
val.val_id_asessor AS ase, 
val.val_ciudad AS ciudad, 
val.val_servicio AS servicio, 
val.val_seasdminuevos AS seminuevo, 
val.val_ventas AS ventas, 
val.val_gte_ven AS gerente, 
val.val_contabilidad as conta, 
CONCAT( u.hus_nombre,"", u.hus_apellido ) AS asessor 
FROM valuaciones_seminuevos AS val 
LEFT JOIN huser u ON u.hus_IDhuser = val.val_id_asessor 
WHERE val.val_ciudad = "'.$ciudad.'" 
'.$and1.' 
'.$and2.' 
'.$and3.' 
'.$and4.' 
'.$and5.''; 

return $this->db->query($qry)->result(); 
}
```

Como hablamos por el chat, esta es la respuesta correcta.